# Hows dividing 1 by function affects the domain

Tags: functions

Given $f(x) = \frac{{4x}}{\sqrt{x}-3}$, what's the domain of $g(x) = \frac{{1}}{f(x)}$ ?

My textbook includes in the answers $x \neq 9$, which I think is erroneous.

Comment: Is that the whole answer in the textbook, or just part of it? Why do you believe $x \neq 9$ is wrong? Can you explain your thinking?

Answer (score 1):

These "*find the domain*" style questions are very frequently poorly worded.  A better worded question would be:

*Find the* **maximal** *subset of $\Bbb R$ such that the expression is well-defined for all elements in our subset and defines a function from our subset to $\Bbb R$.*

That being said, in the case of your specific "function" we have:

$$g(x) = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{4x}{\sqrt{x} - 3}\right)}$$

Common reasons why something fails to be well-defined for a value would be:

- division by zero errors
- taking the square root of a negative value
- taking the logarithm of a non-positive value
- $\vdots$ several others

In your case, the only things we need to worry about are taking square roots of negative numbers and dividing by zero.  We have the following three potential issues:

- division by zero when $x=9$ since the denominator of the denominator, $\sqrt{x} - 3$ would result in zero and the expression would be undefined.
- division by zero when $x=0$ since the denominator $\frac{4x}{\sqrt{x}-3}$ would be zero and the expression would be undefined.
- square root of a negative number when $x<0$ since the root in the denominator of the denominator would be undefined.

All other values would be acceptable.  We find then that our forbidden values of $x$ are $(-\infty,0)\cup \{0\}\cup \{9\}$ and so our maximal subset for which the expression is well defined is:

$$(0,9)\cup (9,\infty)$$

---

Note, the subtle difference between the expression $x$ and the expression $\dfrac{1}{(\frac{1}{x})}$.  The expression on the left is defined for $x=0$ but the expression on the right is *not* defined for $x=0$.  You may have been thinking that $g(x)$ should have been simplified to $\frac{\sqrt{x}-3}{4x}$ but that is not so.  They happen to be equal everywhere except at $x=9$ where $\frac{\sqrt{x}-3}{4x}$ is defined but $\frac{1}{(\frac{4x}{\sqrt{x}-3})}$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

The book is right.

Because $g(x)$ is

$$\frac1{\dfrac{4x}{\sqrt x-3}}$$ and *not*

$$\frac{\sqrt x-3}{4x}.$$

The domain of the first expression is $x>0\land x\ne3$, while that of the second is $x>0$.

If $f(x)$ is not defined, neither is $g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of $f(x)$ includes all the values of $x$, except for $x = 9$ (which makes the denominator of $f(x)$ equal to $0$) and $x < 0$ (since the square root of a negative number is not a real number).

Now $$g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{\frac{4x}{\sqrt{x} - 3}} = \frac{\sqrt{x} - 3}{4x}$$

but the domain of $g(x)$ consists of the $x$-values, excluding $x = 0$ (making the denominator of $g(x)$ equal to $0$). However, the "overall" domain of $g(x)$ would also have to account for the domain of $f(x)$.

Thus the "true" domain of $g(x)$ would be all the positive values of $x$ excluding $x = 9 $.

In set-builder notation:  $\big\{x: 0 < x < 9 $ or $ x > 9 \big\}$

In interval notation: $(0, 9) \cup(9, \infty)$

Comment: Your third identity is not right, the expressions on the left and on the right don't have the same domain. The explanations that follow are just adding a little confusion. The key point is the invalidity of this transformation.